# how can i write a native query in spring boot whith join clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, database, postgresql, spring-boot

I write a native query in spring boot with join clause in PostgreSQL, and here is the query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c.name AS \"c.name\"\n" +
"FROM city c ,state s\n" +
"WHERE c.state_id = s.id \n" +
"AND s.name like :name",nativeQuery = true)
List<City> findCityByStateParamsNative(@Param("name") String name);
```

but i have this issue:
Request processing failed; nested exception is

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT c.name AS "c.name" FROM city c ,state s WHERE c.state_id = s.id
AND s.name like ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:      could not execute query] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Le nom de colonne id n'a pas été trouvé dans ce ResultSet.

who can help me to fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c.name " +
"FROM city c JOIN state s " +
"ON c.state_id = s.id " +
"WHERE s.name = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
List<String> findCityByStateParamsNative(String name);
```

If the problem is not solved, then write in the comment under the answer with a new error.

Comment: than you a lot for your reply  but i have got the same error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Le nom de colonne id n'a pas été trouvé dans ce ResultSet else i need for c.name only not all the entity c, finally thank you again

Comment: @AbderahmenHELAOUI 
I edited answer. If you need only c.name, try with String.

Comment: i can't understand your answer

Comment: @AbderahmenHELAOUI What do you want to get in the method? List of Cities or Strings with the names of cities? If the second, then there should be <String> in the List, in theory.

Comment: @AbderahmenHELAOUI
I was happy to help :)
Please, accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT c.* FROM city c INNER JOIN state s ON c.state_id = s.id WHERE s.name = :name ", nativeQuery = true);
List<City> findCityByStateParamsNative(String name);
```

Comment: first of all I must thank you a lot but i need only for c.name, when i write this: @Query(value = "SELECT c.name AS \"c.name\"\n" +
            "FROM city c\n" +
            "INNER JOIN state s ON c.state_id = s.id \n" +
            "WHERE s.name = :name ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<City> findCityByStateParamsNative(String name); i get the same issue: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Le nom de colonne id n'a pas été trouvé dans ce ResultSet